# Python: Sending to a certain URL based on form submission

Tags: python, html, forms, url, url-routing

I'm trying to create a search bar where it will send users to certain URLs based on the query they typed on the "result" page, e.g. `"/results?<form_search>"`. I've successfully made the version where the result page URL is `/results` but this isn't really what I want.

Here's the HTML script:

```
<!--index.html-->
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="form_search" placeholder="Type here">
</form>
```

Here's the Python script where I direct the result to `/results` URL:

```
#app.py
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

...

# I want to direct this to "/results?<form_search>"
# I think I need to put the line below somewhere but I'm not sure where
# form_search = request.form.get("form_search")

@app.route("/results", methods=["POST"]) # Want to change it to "/results?<form_search>"
def search(form_search):
    ...
    return render_template("results.html", form_search=form_search, results=results)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I barely worked with flask but if you want to have the dynamic URL you need to add it in your @app.route decorator, e.g.: If I want a username to be posted in the URL this is what it would look like:

```
@app.route("/<username>")          # str,int,uuid,float,path also works
def user_name(username=None, post_id=None):     
    return render_template("index.html", name=username)
```

When it comes to getting the data from the form I can show you a similar example as I did in django (I didnt work with flask a while so you might need to experiment a bit yourself) - This is a method as it is created in a class:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
      query = self.request.GET.get(
        "searchrecipe")  # searchrecipe is the name of our input form, means: the value we enter in the form -> This might also work for FLASK, get the data with request.get and FORM NAME
      object_list = Recipe.objects.filter(name__icontains=query) #This filters the data in my database (aftger name) so not relevant for you
      return object_list
```